# Apps Script Google Sheets POP up selecting yes or no always sends the email regardless

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a dropdown menu. When the cell the drop down is in is equal to a certain string a pop up shows up on screen. You answer yes or no.
When you answer yes it sends the email. If you answer no it does not send the email and resets the cell to its previous state.
The issue I am having is that if you select no it does reset to the previous data, but it still sends the email regardless. Please help. I am fairly new and still learning.

**UPDATE:**
Please see the update below. The only var I had to fix was for rData, other than that the script works as intended now. Thank you so much for your time and input. This was a headache for some time.

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  if (ss.getSheetName() == 'Project List' &
    ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 3 &
    ss.getActiveCell().getValue() == "_Complete") {

    var alertPromptText = 'Are you sure you want to select Complete? ' +
      'This action will notify all parties in the next process that this job is ready for fabrication.';

    var promptResponse = ui.alert(alertPromptText, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    if (promptResponse == ui.Button.YES) {

      // CHECK START
      // variable email needs to be fixed. It gets the column of values. 
      // it needs to be converted to a comma separated list of recepients
      var email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange(1, 1, 100).getValues();
      // CHECK END

      var rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,12).getValues();
      sendEmail(email,rData);

       

    } else { // For both 'No' and cancel response to pop-up
      fix(e);
    }
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function sendEmail(email,rData) {
  var first = 0;
  var email = 1;

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("send");
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email");
  var data = ws.getRange("A1:B" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var lj = rData[0][1];
  var j = rData[0][5];
  var d = rData[0][3];
  var p = rData[0][4];
  var m = rData[0][7];
  var desc = rData[0][11];
  var now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  var msg1 = "Laser Job Number: " + lj + " (" + now + ")" +
    "\nProject Job Number: " + j +
    "\nDesigner: " + d +
    "\nDate Project was Submitted to Programming: " + p +
    "\nMaterial used: " + m +
    "\nDescription: " + desc;
    var subject = "Project Ready for Fab";

  
  Logger.log(msg1);

  data.forEach(function(row){
    
    emailTemp.fn = row[first];
    emailTemp.msg = msg1;
    emailTemp.j = j;
    emailTemp.d = d;
    emailTemp.lj = lj;
    emailTemp.p = p;
    emailTemp.m = m;
    emailTemp.desc = desc;
    //emailTemp.cart = cart;

    const htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    
GmailApp.sendEmail(row[email], subject, "Please open with an email client that supports HTML",
{htmlBody: htmlMessage});
  return;

  });
  
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function fix(e) {
  e.range.setNote(e.oldValue);
  e.range.setValue(e.range.getNote());
  e.range.clearNote();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a variable to capture the response to the pop-up.

And then compare the value of the variable for the go-no-go part of the script.

For example:

```
var response = ui.prompt('Alert', 'Are you sure you want to select Complete?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
```

And then

```
if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) { ... }
```

More here in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui).

---

**Update**

Try the following script. You'll need to set the onEdit trigger to run the function `SendMailEdit`

Also, check the code for getting the list of email recepients. Not sure if it will work.

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  if (ss.getSheetName() == 'Project List' &
    ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 3 &
    ss.getActiveCell().getValue() == "_Compvare") {

    var alertPromptText = 'Are you sure you want to select Compvare? ' +
      'This action will notify all parties in the next process that this job is ready for fabrication.';

    var promptResponse = ui.alert(alertPromptText, ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    if (promptResponse.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {

      // CHECK START
      // variable email needs to be fixed. It gets the column of values. 
      // it needs to be converted to a comma separated list of recepients
      var email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange(1, 1, 100).getValues();
      // CHECK END

      var rData = ss.getRange(ss.getActiveCell().getRow(), 1, 1, 12).getValues();
      sendEmail(email, rData);

    } else { // For both 'No' and cancel response to pop-up
      fix(e);
    }
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function sendEmail(email, rData) {
  var lj = rData[0][1];
  var j = rData[0][5];
  var d = rData[0][3];
  var p = rData[0][4];
  var m = rData[0][7];
  var desc = rData[0][11];
  var now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  var msg = "Laser Job Number: " + lj + " (" + now + ")" +
    "\nProject Job Number: " + j +
    "\nDesigner: " + d +
    "\nDate Project was Submitted to Programming: " + p +
    "\nMaterial used: " + m +
    "\nDescription: " + desc;
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Project Ready for Fab", msg);
  return;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function fix(e) {
  e.range.setNote(e.oldValue);
  e.range.setValue(e.range.getNote());
  e.range.clearNote();
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. If I remove any part of the first if statement, then the pop up box shows up regardless of the information in the cell. I have an onEdit trigger set for this.
I need the pop up box to only show up if this condition is met ```if(ss.getSheetName() == 'Project List' & ss.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 3 & ss.getRange(ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()).getValue() == "_Complete")```
If I remove that from the if statement also I get the same result with the popup showing up on every edit, not just the condition wanted. 
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: The biggest thing is that the pop up box is dependent on the cells value of _Complete. As soon as I put that ui.alert into a variable, as soon as I make any edit the box pops up regardless of the data in the cell.

Comment: I don't see the `onEdit(e)` trigger in the script you posted. [See docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=en). Is there more to this script that what you have posted?

Comment: Sorry no that is all of the code. The trigger set is the one you can set under "triggers" in Apps Script.

Comment: I'm driving blind in trying to fix your code. But take a look.